# Pyspark: how to loop through a dataframe column which contains list elements?

Tags: list, pyspark, comparison

I have 2 dataframes (all_posts and headliners). How do I loop through the all_posts['tagged_persons'] column to see if an element of the list AND the corresponding year equal a row of the headliners dataframe?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` the tagged_person column first [refer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=explode). After that join it with headliners based on tagged_person, Artist and year column and then filter the rows where Artist is null will give you the resultant data.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
all_posts = all_posts.select(all_posts.Artist, explode(all_posts.tagged_persons))
cond = [all_posts.tagged_persons == headliners.Artist, all_posts.year == headliners.Year]
join_df = all_posts.join(headliners, cond, 'left')
filter_df = join_df.filter(col("Artist").isNotNull())
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! But this doesn't work as the all_posts dataframe doesn't contain a column 'Artist' (only a column tagged_persons)